# Wifi issue on ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-22.04

I have dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10. Earlier, everything worked fine, but after a few hours, Ubuntu stopped connecting to any wifi network. It says 'wifi connecting' for a minute, then asks for a password and it happens endlessly. How i can fix this issue? What information I can provide to fix it?

Comment: Try a different wireless card;  try upgrading the driver.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.